# Resposta correta porém o uri não aceita

Tags: c

Estou começando a estudar ponteiro e resolvi alterar meus códigos para utilizarem ponteiros,só que tentei enviar essa solução para o uri e ele deu uma mensagem - **In queue** -,não sei onde está o erro,por que as entradas que eu tentei dão a solução que o problema pedi.

[link da questão](https://www.urionlinejudge.com.br/judge/pt/problems/view/1172)

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

int i;
int *vetor(int v[]);

 int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
  int vet[10],*ponte;
  for(i=0;i<10;i++)
{
    scanf("%d",&vet[i]);
}
  ponte=vetor(vet);
    for(i=0;i<10;i++)
    {
        printf("X[%d] = %d\n",i,ponte[i]);
    }
free(ponte);
return 0;
}

int *vetor(int v[])
{
   int *igual=(int*)malloc(sizeof(int)*10);
   for(i=0;i<10;i++)
   {
      if(v[i]<=0)
      {
        igual[i]=1;
      }
      else
      {
        igual[i]=v[i];
      }
}
  return igual;
}
```

Comment: O problema pede o quê? Que você devolva o mesmo vetor, exceto que números não-positivos sejam trocados para 1?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

O código parece bom - se funciona para exemplos que você fez, deve funcionar para qualquer caso.

O problema pode ser que apesar do enunciado não dizer nada, poderem existir números grandes que não caibam em um inteiro simples de 32 bit. Tente substituir todos as ocorrências de  `int`  por `long long` - isso vai fazer seu programam funcionar com inteiros de 64bit, e pode ser o suficiente.

Outra coisa é que o status "in queue" que você diz não é necessariamente erro, e, sim, que seu programa ainda está na fila pra ser testado. Você tem certeza de que tem uma mensagem de erro?  Qual é ela?

E por fim, e na verdade, **o mais importante** desta resposta, já que seu código está essencialmente correto:

Cuidado com a **indentação**!

Ela é opcional em C, mas é feita para nós, humanos, podermos ler seu código. O seu código não tem falhas lógicas e está bem certinho, mas é essencialmente ilegível por pessoas, porque a indentação está quase aleatória.

Escolha uma regra simples e siga-a: não deixe de introduzir um nível de identação "só porque é a chave de uma função" - ela não deve ir na coluna 0. Ou ponha a chave na mesma linha que cria o bloco, ou coloque a chave num nível extra de indentação.

Da mesma forma, o comando `for` que imprime o resultado não está dentro de um bloco separado - ele deve estar alinhado com a linha anterior (`ponte = ...` ) .

Podem parecer detalhes irrelevantes, mas comece a fazer assim e vai ver que mesmo pra você o código fica bem mais fácil de acompanhar.

Comment: Vou seguir suas dicas sobre indentação, segui suas dicas do long long e agora foi aceito

Comment: Acho que o lugar mais completo para ler sobre indentação é o artigo da wikipedia sobre isso: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indentation_style 
Tente alguns nos seus próprios programas, veja o que acha melhor: o importante é consistência. E, lembre-se, que sempre que for participar de algum outro projeto, vale o estio já em uso no projeto.